# Solving differential equation with $y^{'}y^{''}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can this differential equation be solved?

$$y'y'' - t = 0$$

I can't figure this out and the $y'y''$ is giving me trouble since they are attached together.

Comment: Is $t$ a variable or a constant? What is $y$ a function of?

Comment: Hint: What happens when you differentiate $(y')^2$?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more pedestrian idea than what I've seen suggested in answers and comments so far: Let $u=y'$, so that $u'=y''$.  Then you have
$$
uu'-t=0
$$
$$
u\frac{du}{dt} - t =0
$$
$$
u \, du = t\,dt
$$
$$
\frac{u^2}2 = \frac{t^2}2 + \text{constant.}
$$

**Postscript in response to a comment below:**
$$
y' = \pm\sqrt{t^2+C}.
$$
If $y'(1)=1$ then we have
$$
y' = \sqrt{t^2+C}, \text{ so }1 = \sqrt{1^2+C},\text{ and so }C=0.
$$
Now
$$
y' = \sqrt{t^2} = t \text{ (if $t>0$)}.
$$

Comment: What if I have initial conditions y(1)=2 and y'(1)=1? This gets confusing with the + or - before the square root… y' = +- sqrt(t^2 + 2C).  When 1 = +- sqrt(1+2C), then C = 0, and then y' = +- sqrt(t^2 + 0) = +- sqrt(t^2) = +- t… When we go to solve y = +- t^2/2 + D, D can vary based on the +-… Any idea how to solve this with initial condition? @Michael Hardy

Comment: How did you get the +- 2 on the outside of the square root?  Shouldn't it be +-sqrt((t^2) + 2C)?? @Michael Hardy

Comment: Sorry, I made it too complicated.  If $y'(1)$ had been any number besides $1$, those complications would have been needed, but as it is, they were not.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: The expression that is giving trouble is the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}(y')^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Make $z = y'$. So your equation becomes $zz' = t$. Integrating w.r.t $t$, you get: $$\frac{z^2}{2} = \frac{t^2}{2} + c_1, \quad c_1 \in \Bbb R$$
That means: $$y' = \sqrt{t^2 + c_1}\quad c_1 \in \Bbb R$$

(this $c_1$ is twice the old one).

Hence: $$y = \int \sqrt{t^2 + c_1} \ \mathrm{d}t + c_2, \quad c_1, c_2 \in \Bbb R.$$